# PHP change session data for different links

Tags: php, html, session

I have an interesting problem im faced with. I have 6 different items for sale on one page and instead of making 6 different pages for a **detailed view** of each item I wanted to use PHP to redirect all 6 item links from the first page to a **single detailed view page** and just update the picture, description and title of the detailed view page depending on which item link was clicked

So the code

```
<?php $merchandiseData = array('TITLE', 'DESCRIPTION', 'IMG_LINK'); 
      $_SESSION['merchandise'] = $merchandiseData; ?>

<button onClick="window.location='item.html';" class="button"type="button">Add to Cart</button>

<?php $merchandiseData = array('TITLE_2', 'DESCRIPTION_2', 'LINK_2');
      $_SESSION['merchandise'] = $merchandiseData; ?>

<button onClick="window.location='item.html';" class="button">Add to Cart</button>
```

So basically this code goes on 6 times for 6 different links the second page simply gets the data from the $_SESSION['merchandise']; and echo's it out the the document

```
<p class="item-name"><?php echo $_SESSION['merchandise'][0] ?></p>
<div class="picture" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $_SESSION['merchandise'][2] ?>)"></div>
<p class="description"><?php echo $_SESSION['merchandise'][1]; session_destroy(); ?></p>
```

So my problem is that the $merchandiseData will work correctly when i click on the link but every one of the 6 links i click always leads to the same image link, title, and description, and its the last one array of data that I pass to the session on the page. So in the example that I gave above even if I clicked the first button it would still output the data of the second button and Im not sure why?

Any help would be much appreciated! Or if theres an easier way to do it with jquery or javascript id love to know!

Comment: oh, even don't know where to start - try to google difference between server-side code and client-side code. don't use sessions for this task, just use GET arguments to differentiate between products

Comment: every time you set the session data with the same variable, it over writes the previous data. What ever data you set in the last will be available for that session variable. 
$_SESSION['merchandise'] ='data1';
$_SESSION['merchandise'] = 'data2';
$_SESSION['merchandise'] = 'data3';
if you print $_SESSION['merchandise'], it always displays 'data3'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you having that problem is because you storing the merchandise value in same session variable, you are therefore overwriting the initial value and only storing the last value. if you dont mind try this :

```
<?php $merchandiseData = array('TITLE', 'DESCRIPTION', 'IMG_LINK'); 
      $_SESSION['m1'] = $merchandiseData; ?>

<button onClick="window.location='item.html?id=m1';" class="button"type="button">Add to Cart</button>

<?php $merchandiseData = array('TITLE_2', 'DESCRIPTION_2', 'LINK_2');
      $_SESSION['m2'] = $merchandiseData; ?>

<button onClick="window.location='item.html?id=m2';" class="button">Add to Cart</button>
```

then on the second page you do something like:

```
<?php   $id = $_GET['id']; ?>
<p class="item-name"><?php echo $_SESSION[$id][0] ?></p>
<div class="picture" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $_SESSION[$id][2] ?>)"></div>
<p class="description"><?php echo $_SESSION[$id][1]; session_destroy(); ?></p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked I didnt think about my session's being overridden but that makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your PHP code compile 1 time.
if you write in the file for example;

```
$_SESSION['test'] = 1;
$_SESSION['test'] = 2;
```

and try to get `$_SESSION['test']`, you will be get 2. Because you will rewrite your SESSION. I think you need doing this help PHP script, or via Ajax.